# Editor with mode-sensitive syntax highlightning

Tags: auctex, editors, highlighting

Is there a text editor with support for the following (somewhat special) syntax highlightning.
I want to be able to set a different background color for math mode and for normal mode.
(I realize this may be tricky, as one would have to consider "nesting". However, an approximation would be fine.)

I've noticed that a lot of TeX-people swear by Emacs/AUCTeX.
Could it be set up to produce the kind of syntax highlightning I want? If so, how?

Comment: TeXstudio?! Google for screenshots.

Comment: @Sigur, downloaded and tried. I don't see how to achieve the desired coloring. For example, I want a space in text-mode and a space in math-mode to have different background colors.

Comment: I don't change the default highlighting but did you check the configure on options menu?

Comment: @Sigur, yes I checked the "Configure TeXstudio..." options.

Comment: This is dead-simple in Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For emacs, take a look at `font-latex-math-face`.  Where the documentation says `(customize this face)`, you can click that text to be brought to a GUI to set the various properties with previews.

> ```
> Face: font-latex-math-face (sample) (customize this face)
>
> Documentation:
> Face used to highlight math.
>
> Defined in `font-latex.el'.
>
>            Family: unspecified
>           Foundry: unspecified
>             Width: unspecified
>            Height: unspecified
>            Weight: unspecified
>             Slant: unspecified
>        Foreground: #AE81FF
> DistantForeground: unspecified
>        Background: unspecified    <--- note
>         Underline: unspecified
>          Overline: unspecified
>    Strike-through: unspecified
>               Box: unspecified
>           Inverse: unspecified
>           Stipple: unspecified
>              Font: unspecified
>           Fontset: unspecified
>           Inherit: unspecified
> ```

Comment: Yes, this works! If there is a line break in the math, then coloring is done of the "entire remainder of the row" (virtual whitespace?). I think this is logical, but I would prefer if the background color was only applied to actual content, that is, no longer than to the linebreak (and then continuing on the next row). Is this also possible?

Comment: @hal46 That is perhaps a better question for Emacs.SX :) It's certainly possible, but I don't have the time to find/implement a solution.